# Apply for a card: in a new page or on the same product page? What's the best user flow?

Tags: forms, user-expectation, product, signup, online-banking

I have to design a product page for a credit card (it's a banking website). The page consists of info regarding the card, the fees, the rewards, security details, etc.

- My question is: what would be the best place for the Apply for a Card form, at the end of the page, or on a new page, dedicated to the form itself?

On one hand, I looked at other banking websites and most of them have an Apply Now CTA, with a link to a new page, with a sign-up form. BUT, logically speaking, wouldn't be the best flow for the user to have the form right there, and not have to go to a different page to sign up?

What do you think, do you have any experience with this kind of problem? Maybe not in the banking system necessarily.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it depends on what the information page looks like, how much information is present there and after putting the form, whether is it going to look busy and cluttered or not. Secondly, usually, forms are given on the next page so that visitors can focus on the form fields instead of page content and banners etc. A credit card form must have quite a few fields, and putting a long form on a page already filled with information is going to give the user a bad user experience by letting him scroll too much.

Else, if you really want a customer to interact, you can have one mandatory field along with a CTA button, compelling the user to move forward. Check the attached references..[image]

Note: I have given an email address as an example, you can have any of your most important field here.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of bank or company, if it's a company that offers **a single product**, it may be a good option to place the registration form on the same home page. But generally, banks offer multiple products, so placing a form for each case is totally unfeasible and the most used solution is a CTA to apply to the side of the presentation info of each product.

If the registration form is on the same home page, if the bank or company in question has a vision of the future and intentions to grow, sooner or later it will have to remove this form in order to include other products with different types of registration. Even if the product is just a card, there are banks that offer different types of cards, each with a specific requirement.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: **Make the CTA the first and one of the last actions your users see. The form can be the last CTA and the first CTA can lead the user down to it.**

Your situation isn't very different from most product promoting sites out there. You just have to know what the agreed upon information hierarchy/structure is.

Here's how most sites structured:

- Navigation (header)
- a large banner with CTA
- what the product is about
- (optionally) Testimonials
- CTA again
- and finally footer.

The general idea is to present the CTA first and if that fails, try to convince the user. Your last chance is the final CTA. Here's an example of a site that does this well: [Scribe](https://scribehow.com/). Though they show "testimonials" first, but this shouldn't be a problem for your site.

As for the form, you could place it at the bottom, before your footer, as the last CTA. Then make the first CTA link to it.

Personally, I always thought the CTA comes first and last because of the [serial position](https://www.techtarget.com/whatis/definition/serial-position-effect) effect (also check out [primacy](https://thedecisionlab.com/biases/primacy-effect) or [recency](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/psychology/recency-effect#:%7E:text=The%20recency%20effect%20is%20a,exist%20in%20a%20juror%27s%20memory.) effect), very eye opening reads in case you interested.

Comment: Thank you for this info, it's much appreciated! I find it very interesting that psychology and Ux design go so well together!
Just a question regarding this statement "As for the form, you could place it at the bottom, before your footer, as the last CTA. Then make the first CTA link to it." - I had a client who insisted on placing the sign-up form at the start of the page, right in the main banner. Do you think it could be better to place it at the start, or end of a page? I couldn't find anything substantial on this, except for the A/B test.

Comment: @MimyPolina It depends. Large forms at the top should be avoided at all costs. But smaller forms like a newsletter that only asks for name and email, could be fine to add in the banner. But personally I'd avoid it.
An A/B test will be the best route for you to convince your client that a large form at the top is a bad idea, but that's if you even have the time or users to test. You could try making the form more bit sized though. Checkout [TypeForm](https://www.typeform.com/try/typeformbrand/), they have been pushing for more bitsized forms for years now and I agree with them and their style.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Fasih for the point : on a different page the user is more focused :)

I add this other point : the user can be discouraged by seeing a long subscribing form. I suggest to keep it short. If it's need to be a bit long, cut it in differents easy steps. It's easier to complete 3 small steps than a big one. The number of clicks is not as important as the easy of use :)

Hope it's help :)